# How to highlight line chart area on hover (using recharts)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts, recharts

I have a react application (typescript) which has a LineChart (using “recharts” library) as following:

There are different events. Each event is a line. And all lines are shown together in a single chart.
And I have table below the chart that also explains the same events.
I want to change the source code in a way that whenever I hover on any event in the table, corresponding area in the chart is also highlighted.

[image: current chart]

This is how I want to highlight the area of line
[image: This is how I want to highlight]

I've following code:

```
    <ResponsiveContainer height={132} width="100%">
      <LineChart
        data={coords}
        margin={{ left: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0 }}
      >
        <XAxis
          orientation="top"
          height={28}
          axisLine={false}
          dataKey="time"
          type="number"
          domain={[0, SECONDS_PER_DAY]}
          interval={0}
        />
        <YAxis
          yAxisId="left"
          type="number"
          axisLine={false}
          dataKey="status"
          domain={[8, 0]}
          interval={0}
          width={54}
        />
        <YAxis
          yAxisId="right"
          orientation="right"
          type="number"
          axisLine={false}
          dataKey="status"
          domain={[8, 0]}
          interval={0}
        />
        <Line dataKey="" yAxisId="right" hide />
        <Line
          yAxisId="left"
          type="stepBefore"
          dataKey="status"
          dot={false}
          stroke="var(--primary)"
          strokeWidth={4}
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
        />
        <Line
          yAxisId="left"
          type="stepBefore"
          dataKey="dr"
          dot={false}
          stroke="#80B302"
          strokeWidth={4}
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
        />
      </LineChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
```

I've tried to use `onMouseEnter` but not sure how to highlight the area. Can you please tell if there is any builtin feature available by `recharts` ?

Or how I can do it customized way?

Any help / clue will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a built in way to do it, but you can render a custom dot with transparent rect for each line, and when user hovers it to change the opacity, something like this:

```
const [hoveredLine, setHoveredLine] = useState(null)
const lastTime = coords[coords.length - 1].time
const renderDot = ({ cx, width, index }) => {
    if (index === coords.length - 1) return null
    const newWidth = (width - 120) / (lastTime) * (coords[index + 1].time - coords[index].time)
    return (
      <svg x={cx} y={0} width={newWidth} height={300} viewBox={`0 0 ${newWidth} 300`}>
        <rect x={0} width={newWidth} height={300} fill="grey" opacity={index === hoveredLine ? 0.3 : 0}
        onMouseEnter={() => { setHoveredLine(index) }}
           onMouseLeave={() => setHoveredLine(null)}
           />
      </svg>
    )
  }
```

```
        <Line
          yAxisId="left"
          type="stepBefore"
          dataKey="dr"
          dot={renderDot}
          stroke="#80B302"
          strokeWidth={4}
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
        />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated the code with yours one. And I got this https://snipboard.io/f2uzFe.jpg . It is not calculating area correctly. Can you please tell why did you subtracted 120 from width? 

Here is latest code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-g6facg?file=index.tsx
Here is how chart looks like after deploying https://react-ts-g6facg.stackblitz.io

Comment: I need to calculate the correct area. For that, I need the "cx" of the next event then I will set width=next_cx - current_cx. Any idea how to get next cx of next event  in the "renderDot" ?

Comment: there is no way to do it, I subtracted 120, because the chart width contains the axis and paddings, so the chart itself is less then width,

Comment: Hey. Thank you very much for your support. 
I fixed that and it is working. Now, last thing is remaining, I want to have event handler once chart is rendered completely. Is it possible?